# Display the 2nd most paid amount product in every day

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Table sales:

```
  create table sales (  
    Date date,  
    customer_id integer,  
    product_id integer,  
    units_sold integer,  
    paid_amount integer  
    );

Insert into sales (Date, customer_id, product_id, units_sold, paid_amount)  
VALUES  
('2016-01-01', '1', '1', '5', '45'),  
('2016-01-01', '2', '1', '2', '18'),  
('2016-01-01', '3', '2', '7', '35'),  
('2016-01-07', '1', '3', '3', '45'),  
('2016-01-07', '2', '2', '5', '25'),  
('2016-01-07', '4', '2', '5', '25'),  
('2016-01-10', '1', '4', '5', '30'),  
('2016-01-10', '2', '4', '5', '30'),  
('2016-01-10', '4', '5', '6', '60'),  
('2016-01-10', '4', '3', '9', '135'),  
('2016-01-14', '3', '1', '4', '60'),  
('2016-01-14', '2', '3', '6', '90'),  
('2016-01-14', '2', '3', '6', '90');
```

Display the 2nd most    paid    amount  product in  every   day?

I am trying this query: But i am not getting the result for date 14th rest of the date is fine.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT 
       date, 
       customer_id, 
       product_id,
        paid_amount,
       rank() OVER (
         PARTITION BY date 
         ORDER BY paid_amount 
         DESC
        ) 
FROM sales) s 
WHERE rank = 2;
```

Comment: use `dense_rank` instead of `rank`. rank skips numbers if there are multiple rows with the same rank, by that many numbers-1.

Comment: Unrelated, but: please get used to using constants that match the data type of the column. `'45'` is a string value, not a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per vkp:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT 
       date, 
       customer_id, 
       product_id,
        paid_amount,
       dense_rank() OVER (
         PARTITION BY date 
         ORDER BY paid_amount 
         DESC
        ) 
FROM sales) s 
WHERE rank = 2;
```

For context, imagine a list of values, rank and dense_rank order desc:

```
Value    Rank()    Dense_Rank()
100      1         1
90       2         2
90       2         2
80       4         3
70       5         4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   date,
   nth_value(paid_amount, 2)
      OVER (PARTITION BY date
            ORDER BY paid_amount
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
           ) "2nd value"
FROM sales
ORDER BY date;

┌────────────┬───────────┐
│    date    │ 2nd value │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│ 2016-01-01 │        35 │
│ 2016-01-07 │        25 │
│ 2016-01-10 │        30 │
│ 2016-01-14 │        90 │
└────────────┴───────────┘
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Why 30 on 10th and 90 on 14th, It should be 60 on 10th and 60 on 14th.

Comment: I cannot follow 60 on the 14th. You didn't say that you want the third if the first two are equal.